# Is Jessica a virgin forever?

Tags: true-blood

Jessica loses her virginity to Hoyt. Later they have sex again and she becomes 'physically virgin' again, which seems to be a big issue for her.

But then after that you don't hear anything about it anymore.

She doesn't seemed to be bothered at all about it later when she for example seduces Jason. Did she just get used to being a virgin for life?

What happened to change her views?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't got a clearly defined question here.  What are you saying she got used to?  Not being a virgin,  being a virgin again,  or seducing people?

Comment: I edited a bit now.

Comment: Do you mind editing your title? It's attention-getting, sure, but it's not a question nor implying one.

Comment: Yes. It's OK. Go ahead!

Comment: Actually you do hear about it again, when Hoyt and Jessica break up, he comments on how un-fun it is to have to deal with the virginity every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [discussed](http://www.trueblood-online.com/deborah-ann-woll-on-jessica-losing-her-virginity-over-and-over/) by the actress who portrays Jessica. Simply put, the fact that she will remain an eternal *physical* virginal is just something she'll have to learn to <s>live</s> put up with:

> **Q.** ***Do you think sex is something that will ever become pleasurable for Jessica, since she has an intact hymen?***
>
> **DAW** *I think if you resist it and it’s a problem for you, then it’s going to hurt. But if you can somehow release into it and let go and allow
>   it to be that moment of pain that leads to greater pleasure, then
>   that’s a very adult, grown-up way of looking at sex. I’m not sure
>   Jessica’s at that point yet, but I hope she would be with time.*

Comment: Hah, that's from 2010. Of course they forgot about her being an eternal virgin soon after.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - It's not the sort of thing you'd dwell on from a story-telling perspective. After a while I guess it's the sort of thing you'd get used to. Many women suffer from dyspareunia and have regular (if painful) sex lives.